# C# Visual Studio local database path exception (.mdf)

Tags: c#, sql-server, desktop-application

I am developing a project in c# having a database attached. The path I am using to attach the database file is:

```
string connectionString = 
     @"Data Source (LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\[UserName]\Desktop\OOPproject\Nauman(ManagementSystrm\WindowsFormsApplication1\Database1.mdf';Integrated Security=True";
```

When I moved the location of project folder I faced path exceptions as the path changed by moving the folder...

Please help me any general path or something to access database easily.

Comment: What is your new location? [UserName] is a placeholder just in your question or it remained in the connection string by mistake?

Comment: If i get your question right, you are looking for `string currentPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;`. Just connect this string with your location and it will find your DB everytime.

Comment: The **best solution** would be to put the database **on the server** where it belongs - and then just reference that server and the logical database name from your application and stop fiddling around with `.mdf` files altogether....

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the path to your database relative. You can do this by adding the particular database to the project then if you want the database to be on the WebService than you can use:

```
 string connectionString = @"Data Source" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Database1.mdf") + @";Integrated Security=True";
```

If the database is on a physical location then use:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=" + Request.PhyicalApplicationPath + "\\Database1.mdf" + @";Integrated Security=True";
```

Depending on the location of the database the path may need to be adjusted.